# hypothesis testing doubt

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study, least-squares, delta-method

I have the OLS regression model:

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \beta_3X_3 + \beta_4X_4 + \epsilon$

I want to check the hypothesis:

Ho : $\beta_2*\beta_3$ = 1

Will I use the Delta method to form the gradients of function $\beta_2*\beta_3$ since it seems a non linear restriction and then use a wald statistic? Which test is recommended here? LR, LM or Wald?